# Ho to fix the `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND marketplace.visualstudio.com` when running a vs code project in Dev Container mode (with proxy pac and VPN)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

***Given:***

1. machine connected through VPN (SitePoint) to company private network
2. vscode runs with the proxy pac configuration switch `--proxy-pac-url=http://<myhostname>/<path_to_proxypac>/proxy.pac"`:
3. any extensions can be seen and installed successfully
4. python 3 project opened with vscode
5. development container configuration files... (Python 3) added to project
6. Add the following extensions to .devcontainer.json

   ```
     "extensions": [
       "ms-python.python",
       "himanoa.python-autopep8",
       "wholroyd.jinja",
       "magicstack.MagicPython",
     ]
   ```
7. Reopened project in container

***Expected:***

- extensions configured in .devcontainer.json are successfully installed in the Dev Container mode vs code.

***Actual:***

1. the list of `DEV CONTAINER: PYTHON 3 - INSTALLED` is empty
2. and got the following error in vs code terminal

```
    [27528 ms] Installing extensions...
    [27528 ms] getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND marketplace.visualstudio.com
    getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND marketplace.visualstudio.com
    getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND marketplace.visualstudio.com
    getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND marketplace.visualstudio.com
    [27528 ms] Exit code 1
```

***Mentions:***
1. I can install extensions from Dev Container mode vs code.

***What am I supposed to do to address this problem?***

***Could this be an issue or feature request for `Remote-Containers` extension?***

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

In Visual Studio Code, go to:
**File** > **Preferences** > **Settings**

Then click on tab **User** > **Application** > **Proxy**

Enter your proxy address in the field, as an example:
http://proxy_userid:proxy_password@proxy_ip:proxy_port

If your password contains special characters, replace it with the URL Encode value. See here: http://www.cjdinfo.com.br/utilitario-tabela-caracteres

Or try it:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network